# Prevent rm -r of btrfs snapshots

Tags: rm, btrfs

I would like to use btrfs snapshots as a safety measure in case of accidental `sudo rm -rf /*` or similar but unfortunately you can delete readonly snapshots with `rm -r`.

Can I disable this "feature" somehow?

Comment: Don't give `sudo` access to people you think may destroy the system. Keep off-line (external) backups of important data.

Comment: just don't mount the root file system, just the subvolumes

Comment: @they The person most likely to destroy my system is myself. As I mentioned, this is for protection against *accidental* removal (by people who are *supposed* to have sudo access). Backups are not the topic of this post. This is for keeping around rollback points for convenience, not any kind of data safety.

Comment: @MarcusMüller not possible when the system needs access to the snapshot directory for continuous snapshotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `rm -rf` does *not* work on real snapshots.

In my test setup, I used an empty subvolume/snapshot to keep it simple. `rmdir` is allowed to delete subvols/snapshots but obviously only works if they're empty.
If the snapshot contains even one file, `rm -rf` errors out on that file with `Read-only file system` while trying to delete that file and then can't `rmdir` the snapshot itself anymore because there's a file in it.